# How to record trackevent in google analytics?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, event-tracking

This is my analytics code so far:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'XXXX', {cookieDomain: 'none', legacyCookieDomain: 'none'});ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I am trying to record an event like this:

```
<a style="
    color: #00b258; font-size: 15px;" onclick="ga('_trackEvent', 'Submit an inquiry', 'Click Submit Inquiry', 'Opened Inquiry form on ' + document.url);return true;" href="http://test.com">Submit An Inquiry</a>
```

But when I go in firebug net panel no request is sent. What am I missing? Is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mixing up the tracking code a little I think.  It should look more like this.  The first item should be `Send` not _`trackevent`.

```
<a href='#' onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'test', 4);"> Test Event</a>
```

---

Trying to fix yours:  Im not sure its going to let you add the document.url but let me know if it does :)

```
<a style="color: #00b258; font-size: 15px;" onclick="ga('send', 'Submit an inquiry', 'Click Submit Inquiry', 'Opened Inquiry form on ' + document.url);" href="http://test.com">Submit An Inquiry</a>
```

Link for reference: [Event Tracking - Web Tracking (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)